# How to scale dimensions of a model while keeping the other dimensions proportional ??

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing, dimensions

[image]

[image]

I want to make my model "4cm" in order to be able to 3D print the model. I've applied the scale of my model, and I am trying to change the dimensions of the Y-AXIS from 11.817 m to 4cm, while the other X and Z axis scale proportionally. 
But, I the X and Z dimensions don't scale to their proportional sizes to the Y-Axis of 4cm, and turn into X:0 and Z:0 .
Is there anything im doing wrong? or another way?

Comment: Well.. The quick & dirty method is to just press S and move your cursor until the Y dimension is what you want :P.

Comment: Then how would I correctly apply my scale? And I know that method, but i want it to be as accurate as it can be.

Comment: Alt + A makes my Timeline start to play. :/

Comment: I did that, and selected "Scale" but it still wont scale proportionally :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you could follow:

1. Select your model in Object mode, Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
2. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> and start scaling.
3. Scale close to the value you want, and then hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> to fine tune the scaling as you move your mouse.
4. <kbd>LMB</kbd> to complete the scaling operation.

Comment: Thank you! Wow! The Shift helped alot!!! xD I actually got the Y dimensions to be 4cm!! While the rest scaled proportionally too! :D Thanks!!!

Comment: It's still a dirty workaround... is there maybe some plugin that's just able to lock axes for proportional scale? It's so weared that sometimes Blender misses some most basics, simple and so needful features...

Comment: @ LDCO are you refering to scaling in a single axis? Then it's definitely a feature in blender. If you want to only scale on say x axis hit "x" after you hit "s" for scaling operation. If you want to only scale on say y axis hit "y" and so on. Now say you want to scale in both X and Y but exclude Z axis. You hit "Shift + Z" to exclude scaling in Z. Hope that helps.

Comment: Blender have become my production tool. I suggest looking into blender as blender has a workflow far more superior than software like 3dsmax in some of the basic modeling sense. As I came from 3dsmax production environment in the past, I can attest to that.